# How to get an ongoing index of an React element in a recursive loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested data structure like this:

```json
[
  { title: "A" },
  {
    title: "B",
    children: [
      { title: "B.1" },
      {
        title: "B.2",
        children: [{ title: "B.2.1" }, { title: "B.2.2" }]
      }
    ]
  },
  { title: "C" }
]
```

Now I want to render each item with an ongoing index in my React app. That's how I tried it, but due to obvious reasons, the index isn't ongoing but splitted up in index paths for each iteration:

```
function List({ items, index }) {
  return items.map((item) => {
    index++;
    return <Item key={item.title} item={item} index={index} />;
  });
}

function Item({ item, index }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Titel: {item.title}, Index: {index}
      </div>
      {item.children && <List items={item.children} index={index} />}
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  let index = 0;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <List
        index={index}
        items={[
          { title: "A" },
          {
            title: "B",
            children: [
              { title: "B.1" },
              {
                title: "B.2",
                children: [{ title: "B.2.1" }, { title: "B.2.2" }]
              }
            ]
          },
          { title: "C" }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is what I get:

```
Titel: A, Index: 1
Titel: B, Index: 2
Titel: B.1, Index: 3
Titel: B.2, Index: 4
Titel: B.2.1, Index: 5
Titel: B.2.2, Index: 6
Titel: C, Index: 3
```

And this is want I want:

```
Titel: A, Index: 1
Titel: B, Index: 2
Titel: B.1, Index: 3
Titel: B.2, Index: 4
Titel: B.2.1, Index: 5
Titel: B.2.2, Index: 6
Titel: C, Index: 7
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this without flattening the array?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
class Indexer {
    constructor(){
        this.index=0
    }
    next(){
        let result = this.index
        this.index += 1
        return result
    }
}

function MyComponent(){

    let indexer = new Indexer()


    return <MyItem key={indexer.next()} label="1.1">
               <MyItem key={indexer.next()} label="1.1.1">
               <MyItem key={indexer.next()} label="1.1.2">
           </MyItem>
}
```